# How to group values into intervals with logarithmic scale in Excel or R?

Tags: r, excel, scale, intervals, logarithm

I have a pivot table with a list of values (money) and their frequency in different categories:

[image]

The list is 4573 values long and goes from 0 to 65mln. I need to create intervals of these values in a way that they would fit the logarithmic scale like in this example:

[image]

How to group the existing list into these intervals using preferably excel or r?

Comment: I guess those values are numeric. In Excel, you can group them in Pivot Table. Or in original datasource, add a column with the logaritmic value and then Group that field in the Pivot Table. Check [Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)

Comment: Thank you! Just figure out to use if function for logarithmic value. Now it should work.